# Async foreach in javascript with step of n

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, foreach, async.js

If I run this, I will get 1, 2, ..., 50 in my console.

```
keys = [1, 2, 3, ..., 50];
async.forEach(keys, function (key, callback){
    console.log(key);
    callback();
}
```

But I want to have an step of 3. I want to get: 1, 4, 7, ...
like this for loop:

```
for (let key = 1; key <= 50; key = key + 3) {

}
```

How can I achieve this with async?

Comment: If `keys` is set to `[1, 2, 3...` initially, just multiply by 3 and subtract to get to `1, 4, 7` on each iteration? Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const res = keys.reduce((acc, elem, i) => i % 3 == 0 ? [...acc, elem] : acc, []);`

Will give you the result `res` of:

`[1, 4, 7, 10, 13, ..., 48]; // Every 3rd index`

Where `i % 3` controls the step. So, if you want to increment by 4 each time you could change this to `i % 4` etc...

Thus, you can use this in your code like so:

```
keys = [1, 2, 3, ..., 50];
let stepKeys = keys.reduce((acc, elem, i) => i % 3 == 0 ? [...acc, elem] : acc, []);
async.forEach(stepKeys, function (key, callback){
    console.log(key);
    callback();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what `async.forEach` is, but assuming you're just trying to do a normal `forEach` with 3 steps as you said, here's my approach:

`forEach` is not really appropriate for usages where you manipulate your index (specially in more hardcore cases, where your index might change within the loop), but as a quick hack, you can do the following:

```
keys.forEach((key, index) => {
  if(index % 3 === 0) {
  // Only true when it's a multiple of 3
  // Do your loop body
  } 
});
```

Note that `forEach` takes a callback, where the first parameter is the current value, and optional parameters (among which is the current index), see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: This answer is much more transparent